# Best iCalendar library for Java?

Tags: java, icalendar

I'm looking for a library to handle [iCalendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar) data in Java.

Open source, well-documented implementations with a good object model are preferred.  iCal parsing capabilities are less important to me, but still nice to have.

Does anyone have any recommendations?

Comment: See the [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) site.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I had limited success with [iCal4j](https://github.com/ical4j/ical4j) ([intro](http://ical4j.sourceforge.net/introduction.html)) on a project last year.

It seems to be a fairly popular choice for ical work in the java community.

If I remember correctly the API can be slightly confusing at first glance.
However It's pretty solid in the long run.

Good luck, 
Brian

Comment: I had lots of problems with iCal4J. Weird date time objects, concurrency exceptions (Parser can only be called on the main thread wtf?). Don't recommend it.

Comment: Agreed.  Just tried to use it and it is pretty bad, IMO.  Class names shadow standard JDK names (Calendar, Date, etc.).  Really strange patterns and odd code smells.  Depends on SLF4j.

Comment: As other have posted the iCal4j library is not easy to figure out and there is documentation on the website that no longer works.   After wasting a bunch of time researching it and trying it, I went with biweekly mentioned above and it was much easier to deal with.

Answer (score 66):

A challenger appears!  Please give [biweekly](https://github.com/mangstadt/biweekly) a try.  I'm looking for lots of feedback on how it can be improved.

Comment: I found biweekly much easier to get started with and use for my simple need of generating an ics email attachment. It also has fewer dependencies, which is always nice.

Comment: Seems good, I tried switching to your library from Ical4j, but the parse function throws a stackOverflowError on large ics files.. But your library is indeed more simple and smaller ;)

Comment: @Jordy Thanks for the complements. :) I've fixed the problem you described.  It had to do with the way in which the `List.subList()` method was being called.  The fix will be included in the next release.  Thanks for letting me know about it! :D

Comment: +1   json support and "normal" Date/Time handling are benefits, but killer feature was that importing a (large) ics in ical4j failed while biweekly just swallowed it right away ...

Comment: +1 nicer to work with than ical4j for processing .ics files.. is there something similar to `net.fortuna.ical4j.model.Component.calculateRecurrenceSet()?`

Comment: Hi @antak. You can use the `RecurrenceRule.getDateIterator()` method to iterate over all the dates in a recurrence rule.

Comment: Hi @Michael, I've some issue with updating events maybe you can give a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33675735/how-to-create-and-send-update-to-existing-event-by-uisng-biweekly-library-and-ja  And thank you for your work, it's very intuitive to use in comparison with other solutions.

Comment: Hi @Anatoly.  See my answer.

Comment: Here I was thinking I was going to have to parse this by hand. A simple library is just what I needed. Awesome!

Comment: here my code with biweekly to generate a couple of date start and date end : https://stackoverflow.com/a/56740923/9134193

Comment: It is very easy to use and effective. Thanks man