# how to read .ics file and add data to Google Calendar in android?

Tags: android

I have the calendar.ics file. I have to read that file from my application and transfer the data in to Google calendar in android. I am new to android. I need some help to do this.Can anyone help me to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calendar application that is part of the Android open source project is not part of the Android SDK. Some devices will not have it installed, and the application may change in future releases of Android.

Hence, you need to use the appropriate [Google Calendar GData APIs](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/), no different than you would for working with a Google Calendar anywhere else.

With respect to parsing iCalendar files in Java, see [this other StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33901/best-icalendar-library-for-java).