# Create and send a ics calendar appointment from java to android

Tags: java, android, cordova, icalendar

I want to create a  calendar appointment form my java aplication and send it to Android devices.

I'm googling for two days but I dont have an idea what it could be make. 
The first step is create a .ics file and then, send a email to a device with the appointment.

How I can create this .ics file from java?

Thanks a lot

Comment: This should be possible with the libraries proposed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33901/best-icalendar-library-for-java

Comment: thanks Simon, it could be the solution