# Extensible Java Calendaring/Task Server

Tags: java, calendar, server

I have a Java project where I will need to create an application to manage calendering events and tasks. This application be part of a larger project and will need to implement pretty specific functionality. At it's heart though, it will have events with dates, reminders, alarms, to-do lists with deadlines. It will also need to share events between different users and groups.

It seems to me that the core functions of this system must be something that has been pretty much solved, and I am wondering if there is a java system / library that implements it?

I have looked into the following :
- bedework : seems to implement everything I need, and a lot more. I have looked into it, but it does not seem like the source code is documented or that the core functions are made to be integrated into an other project ( I do not need their web interface or the extra features )
- cosmo : seems abandonned
- Oracle Calendar Server : Does not seem to be open source 
- Milton IO seems like something I would use if I wanted to support CalDav, but I still need to implement the calendar back end

Pointers? Solutions? Recommendations?

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library**, tutorial or other off-site resource **are off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: This question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33901/best-icalendar-library-for-java, while closed as off-topic, has a few answers and comments you might find useful.