# Java mail for accessing POP3/IMAP server calender events Android

Tags: android, jakarta-mail

I have worked on ews api,it provides WellKnownFolderName.Calendar folder to access meeting and appointment. 
My server is imap and  not exchange server so now I'm using java mail. But there is no specific folder like calender to get meeting. I can access inbox folder though.Can anyone help me how to filter meeting from inbox.

Comment: Other non-Exchange IMAP servers don't usually store calendar data in mail folders.  If someone sends you an invitation you can find it in your Inbox.  Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes that's right . Based on message.getContentType().contains("TEXT/CALENDAR") , i'm getting calendar events from inbox but how to read content send like time and attendees of meeting

Comment: Using JavaMail, you can find the body part of the message with MIME type text/calendar (or whatever).  You can then use the getContent method on that body part to read the [iCalendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar) data, which you can either parse yourself or find some existing [Java library that will parse iCalendar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33901/best-icalendar-library-for-java) for you.